# What happens in JavaScript when defining objects on Constructor Variables

Tags: javascript, prototype

Say I have defined a Constructor and a prototype in Javascript like this:

```
MyGame.Player = function(){
    this.somevar = 42;
};
MyGame.Player.prototype = {
    somevar: null,
    someFunc: function(){}
};
```

What will happen if I do the following:

```
MyGame.Player.Helper = function(){...}
MyGame.Player.Helper.prototype = {...}
```

- Will javascript allow this actually?
- Will the Helper appear as ownProperty in an instance of MyGame.Player() ?
- Can I always create new Helper objects even if I don't have a Player object?

Comment: Have you tried it out ?

Comment: Before using it I just wanted to make sure that there is nothing bad or dangerous about doing so :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will javascript allow this actually?

Sure. It's just a function as property of an object. In classical OOP this would be called a *class method*.

> Will the Helper appear as ownProperty in an instance of MyGame.Player()?

Nope. It's a property of the *constructor function*, not of the instance. The instance only gets all properties assigned to `this` in the constructor and anything from the `prototype`. It doesn't inherit properties of the constructor function.

> Can I always create new Helper objects even if I don't have a Player object?

Sure, because you call `new MyGame.Player.Helper`, not `new (new MyGame.Player).Helper`.

Put another way, you just assigned a function to `MyGame.Player.Helper`, of course you can call it via `MyGame.Player.Helper()`, because that's where you just put it.

Comment: @Brian Have a look at standard Javascript objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date, they're clearly segregated into *"Methods"* and *"Instance/Prototype methods"*. Same thing.